# i have errors when run spring boot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am beginer with java and Spring boot and when i build simple project and run it then i get errors about can not load main class but i don't why ?? somebody can help me?? Thank a lot!

Here my struct of my project: 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxX3R.png)

and my main class:

```
package app3;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App3.class, args);
    }
}
```

my controller file

```
package app3;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

// Đánh dấu đây là một Controller
// Nơi tiếp nhận các reqquest từ phía người dùng
@Controller
public class WebController {

    // Đón nhận request GET
    @GetMapping("/") // Nếu người dùng request tới địa chỉ "/"
    public String index() {
        return "index"; // Trả về file index.html
    }
}
```

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>app3</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-learning</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-learning</name>
    <description>Everything about Spring Boot</description>


    <dependencies>

        <!--spring mvc, rest-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>    
                <mainClass>app3.App3</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and simple html file in reources dict

then i type command  `mvn spring-boot:run -e`

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< app3:spring-boot-learning >----------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-learning 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ spring-boot-learning >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ spring-boot-learning <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Error: Could not find or load main class app3.App3
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app3.App3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.576 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-11T23:37:45+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

when i type `mvn clean spring-boot:start -e`
i get the log:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< app3:spring-boot-learning >----------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-learning 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:start (default-cli) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Error: Could not find or load main class app3.App3
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app3.App3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.362 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-11T23:39:46+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:start (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: Could not contact Spring Boot application: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
[ERROR]         java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:start (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: Could not contact Spring Boot application
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not contact Spring Boot application
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect (RMIConnector.java:370)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect (JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.SpringApplicationAdminClient.connect (SpringApplicationAdminClient.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.execute (StartMojo.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)

    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup (RegistryContext.java:137)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup (GenericURLContext.java:207)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup (InitialContext.java:409)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI (RMIConnector.java:1839)

    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.execute (StartMojo.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection (TCPChannel.java:300)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection (TCPChannel.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall (UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup (RegistryImpl_Stub.java:112)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup (RegistryContext.java:133)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup (GenericURLContext.java:207)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup (InitialContext.java:409)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI (RMIConnector.java:1839)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer (RMIConnector.java:1813)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect (RMIConnector.java:302)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect (JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.SpringApplicationAdminClient.connect (SpringApplicationAdminClient.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.execute (StartMojo.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill (BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read (BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte (DataInputStream.java:270)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection (TCPChannel.java:239)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection (TCPChannel.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall (UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup (RegistryImpl_Stub.java:112)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup (RegistryContext.java:133)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup (GenericURLContext.java:207)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup (InitialContext.java:409)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI (RMIConnector.java:1839)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer (RMIConnector.java:1813)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect (RMIConnector.java:302)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect (JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.SpringApplicationAdminClient.connect (SpringApplicationAdminClient.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo$CreateJmxConnector.call (StartMojo.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.execute (StartMojo.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForForkedSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.waitForSpringApplication (StartMojo.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.StartMojo.runWithForkedJvm (StartMojo.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

sombody can help me! thank a lot!

Comment: define main class with @springbootapplication annotation

Comment: @dassum sorry, i fixed my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `<packaging>pom</packaging>` from your `pom.xml` and then run `mvn clean install`

it should work

> you have used packaging type **pom**, you should use the jar, The
>   default packaging type is jar, If you don't have any it will use
>   packaging as jar
>
> The packaging type of a Maven project specifies the type of artifact
>   the project produces. There are many built-in Maven packaging types
>   (for example, jar, war, and ear).
>
> A pom type is packaging a kind container of submodules, a submodule is
>   represented by a subdirectory in the same directory

Comment: you have used packaging type **pom**, you should use jar, The default packaging type is jar, If you don't have any it will use packaing as jar

Packaging type of a Maven project specifies the type of artifact the project produces. There are many built-in Maven packaging types (for example, jar, war, and ear).

A pom type is packaging a kind container of submodules, submodule is represented by a subdirectory in the same directory